# Value not able to be inserted in table in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to insert a a value in to my database table, but not able to insert it. It was insert a value till comment fields after not able to insert for country and datepickers customer_info table in wordpress database. Is that the right way to do?

Here is my html code:

```
<div style="   text-align: center;">
   <form action="#v_form" method="post" id="v_form">
    <label for="visitor_name"></label>
    <input class="contedd" type="text" name="visitor_name"  id="visitor_name" placeholder="Your Name"/>
    <label for="visitor_name"></label>
    <input class="contedd" type="text" name="visitor_email" id="visitor_email" placeholder="An email id we can reach you at." />
    <label for="Your Number"></label>
    <input class="contedd" type="text" name="YourNumber" id="YourNumber"  placeholder="Your Number"  />
    <br>
    <label for="comment"></label>
     <select class="contedd" name="npofpeople" style="  margin-top: 10px;    padding: 6px;    width: 100%;    font-size: 15px;    border-radius: 1px;    border: 1px solid #811a53;">
     <option value="" disabled selected>How many people you will be ?</option>
    <option value="1-5">1-5</option>
    <option value="6-10">6-10</option>
     <option value="10-15">10-15</option>
    <option value="above">above</option>
     </select>
    <label for="datepicker"></label>
    <input class="contedd" type="text"  name="datepicker" id="date_ex" placeholder="When do you want to visit us ?">
     <label for="comment"></label>
    <textarea class="contedd" name="comment" rows="5" cols="40" placeholder="We will arrange for your travel . Please give your full address"  style="
     margin-top: 10px; padding: 6px; width: 100%;font-size: 15px;border-radius: 1px; border: 1px solid #811a53;"></textarea>
    <label for="country"></label>
   <select class="contedd" name="country" style="  margin-top: 10px;    padding: 6px;    width: 100%;    font-size: 15px;    border-radius: 1px;    border: 1px solid #811a53;
    ">
              <option value="" disabled selected>Country</option>
              <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
              <option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
              <option value="AL">Albania</option>
    </select>
          <input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="submit" style="text-align: center; margin: 0 auto; margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;">
</form>
</div>
<?php
$html = ob_get_clean();
// does the inserting, in case the form is filled and submitted
if ( isset( $_POST["submit_form"] ) && $_POST["visitor_name"] != "" ) {
    $table = $wpdb->prefix."my_table";
    $name = strip_tags($_POST["visitor_name"], "");
      $visitor_email = strip_tags($_POST["visitor_email"], "");
       $YourNumber = strip_tags($_POST["YourNumber"], "");
        $comment = strip_tags($_POST["comment"], "");
         $npofpeople = strip_tags($_POST["npofpeople"], "");
           $datepicker = strip_tags($_POST["datepicker"], "");  
            $country = strip_tags($_POST["country"], "");  


    $wpdb->insert( 
        $table, 
        array( 
            'name' => $name,
             'visitor_email' => $visitor_email,
             'YourNumber' => $YourNumber,
             'comment' => $comment,
              'npofpeople' => $npofpeople,
               'datepicker' => $datepicker,
               'country ' => $country ,
               array( '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s' ) 

        )
    );
    $html = "<p>Your name <strong>$name</strong> was successfully recorded. Thanks!!</p>";
}
```

Comment: post your table stucture

Answer (score 0):

SORRY FOR CAPS.
No, joke aside.
Please look at the WPDB documentation, the insert method expects 3 parameters, not two. Take your format array out of your data array like so:

```
      $wpdb->insert( 
            $table, 
            array( 
                'name' => $name,
                 'visitor_email' => $visitor_email,
                 'YourNumber' => $YourNumber,
                 'comment' => $comment,
                  'npofpeople' => $npofpeople,
                   'datepicker' => $datepicker,
                   'country ' => $country

            ),
 array( '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') 

        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. remove the space in country field `'country ' => $country` to `'country' => $country`

```
$wpdb->insert( 
            $table, 
            array( 
                'name' => $name,
                 'visitor_email' => $visitor_email,
                 'YourNumber' => $YourNumber,
                 'comment' => $comment,
                  'npofpeople' => $npofpeople,
                   'datepicker' => $datepicker,
                   'country' => $country

            ),
        array( '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') 

        );
```